# Using a variable from module to add custom CSS in decorator

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have an NativeScript Angular app for which I want to use separate CSS for tablets. Therefore I am checking the `deviceType` through `tns-core-modules/platform` and add in the decorator the tablet CSS if relevant like below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DeviceType } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/enums';
import { device } from 'tns-core-modules/platform/platform';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    './login.component.css',
    device.deviceType === DeviceType.Tablet ? './login.component.tablet.css' : ''
  ]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
}
```

This works fine when I run a regular `tns run <platform>`, however when I want to create a bundle (and webpack is used) then I get an error:

> Only initialized variables and constants can be referenced in decorators because the value of this variable is needed by the template compiler in 'device'

I think that I understand what it is complaining about in principle, but I would expect `device` to have initialized by the time my component gets instantiated, since device comes from the `tns-core-modules` module.

Can anyone think of a way to allow this kind of use? I have seen this [blog](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/tablet-support-for-nativescript-with-angular) where Eddy does something similar but at a later stage in `ngOnInit`, but that is too late for me, because somehow the tablet CSS is not applied to modals.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are looking for just different stylings based on device type then [nativescript-platform-css](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-platform-css) might be helpful here.

Comment: @manoj yeah I tried using that one but it does not work in modals at all and it requires /deep/ which messes up encapsulation. It turns out that the CSS :host selector is not (properly) implemented in NS yet (I opened a feature request for it a while back).

Answer (score 1):

It surprises me a little that it isn't working in `ngOnInit` since your view hasn't yet been constructed. You could push it even sooner by using the `constructor`, but you might run into the same problem.

As a last resort, you could also just make a separate component and choose which one is included in your template with an `ngIf`.

It might be worthwhile investigating why your implementation of Eddy's example doesn't work, though.